# Type 'Foo<T>' is not assignable to type 'T extends string ? string | Foo<T> : Foo<T>'

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following code:

```
class Foo<T> {
  x?: T extends string ? string | Foo<T> : Foo<T>
}

function bar<T>(): Foo<T> {
  const x: Foo<T> = { }
  return { x }
}
```

Why does the compiler yield the following error for `return { x }`?

```
Type 'Foo<T>' is not assignable to type 'T extends string ? string | Foo<T> : Foo<T>'. ts(2322)
```

`Foo<T>` should satisfy both `string | Foo<T>` and `Foo<T>`, so it should also satisfy the type of `Foo.x` regardless of whether `T extends string` or not, right?

Comment: It's a current limitation of TypeScript.  The compiler completely *defers* the evaluation of a distributive generic conditional type (like `T extends string ? ... : ...`), so it has no idea what kinds of value might be assignable to it.  See [ms/TS#46429](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/46429) for a pull request which implemented the current behavior; performance is just too terrible if the compiler tries to do this.

Comment: So that's the answer to the question as asked. If you want a workaround I'd refactor any conditional types where the left and right overlap to move the overlap out, like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NV4k5W) shows.  Does this fully address the question? If so I'll write up an actual answer post.  If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz As for the refactor you suggested, it unfortunately doesn't work for my case, since the property definition is actually written in a third-party library. So I'll be forced to do something like `return { x: { } as any }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that, no matter what `T` is, the type `Foo<T>` should be assignable to `T extends string ? string | Foo<T> : Foo<T>`.  This is actually a little tricky to verify, since  if `T` is a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) (e.g., `number | Date`), then `Foo<T>` will *not* be a union type (e.g., `Foo<number | Date>`), but `T extends string ? string | Foo<T> : Foo<T>` *will be* a union type (e.g., `Foo<number> | Foo<Date>`).  That's because `T extends string ? ... : ...` is a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) which splits unions into their members before evaluation, and reunites into a new union afterward.  So the fact that the conditional type is always assignable to `Foo<T>` independently of `T` depends specifically on the definition of `Foo<T>`, and the fact that it is *covariant* in `T` (see [this Q/A for a discussion of variance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66411491/2887218)).

But the compiler does not see this.  Why?

---

Well, generally speaking, the evaluation of [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depend on [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters is *deferred* by the compiler.  There was some work done in [microsoft/TypeScript#46429](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/46429) to allow a type to be assignable to a conditional type if it was assignable to both the true and false branches of that type, but this only works for *non*-distributive types that don't use [the `infer` keyword](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types).  Since you have a distributive type, it doesn't work here.

So, evaluation of `T extends string ? string | Foo<T> : Foo<T>` is deferred until such time as `T` is specified.  Inside the body of `bar()`, `T` is unspecified, so the conditional type is not evaluated there.  It is essentially *opaque* to the compiler, and it won't be able to verify that you can assign a value to it, unless that value is also of the identical conditional type.  And `Foo<T>` is not.  So the compiler complains.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/HYQwtgpgzgDiDGEAEB5ATgSwOZIN4FgAoJJeAGxCiiQDEB7OgHgBUA+PIkkgDwH4AuJMyQRuAFwjAAJtShjMwHLyRyFOAD60GLdoPpM2nJAF8iRqRHIg0yeHWBykAV2AZ7+vduBOwAIwho7Jr6jAAiIBKsANxGdg5iSMD2AKqu7gyeTN5+AUia4ZFIALzOacD6MYRGAGYu8GJuwEi+1joAFACUmTocxFxxjtzdbMV4pn0kNmJOaE24SNwmRuPjRFZUWgbsBH18w0FIbcKiEtKy8hiKSMqqlziCwBAAbgEdRKuEtcD1jc2tbJ19r0SAMEkNNj0SrhxpMINNZngFktCMYgA)