# How to define the return type to be something or undefined only if some generic parameter may be undefined too?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'd like to express a custom utility function to have its return type to be nullable only if the input is nullable too.

The actual goal is to limit the need to check for return type or to hard code type assertion (working in strict mode)

For exemple, imagine a dummy `toUpper` function that accept a string.

- If my incoming parameter is `string`, I'm sure my return will never be `undefined`
- If my incoming parameter is `string | undefined`, my function may return `undefined`

Like this:

```js
// actually this strings are returned from other code
const str1 : string = 'foo'; 
const str2 : string | undefined = 'bar';
const str3 : string | undefined = undefined;

const upper1 = toUpper(str1); // upper1 should be typed as string
const upper2 = toUpper(str2); // upper2 should be typed as string | undefined
const upper3 = toUpper(str3); // upper3 should be typed as string | undefined
```

I tried this:

```js
const toUpper = <TInput extends string | undefined>(
    input: TInput
    ): TInput extends string ? string : (string | undefined) => {
    if(!input)  return undefined;

    return input.toUpperCase();
}
```

But it does compile with the error `Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'TInput extends string ? string : string | undefined'.` (on line `return undefined`)

How can I fix this ?

Here's a [playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBAcwKYwMpgLZNTATgSwgTgF44AKQgBwFcYAuOWAogSkecOJID44BvYHGFxcKGrghwARNTpx8UGXADUCiLRgBuYAF9goSLEQp0WHCwQBZAIYBPAEZIAqhAAmSAGaEkb0hTkGJjwudmDLOAAfOBp3Lx8-XgEhETEYCSlKDToAOlgbXBgoAHV8GAALcmkbaVZWOAB+dU04RliPbwhfHX1DaHgYMGcqKiRcfwAeABUASWz4JAAPGCR3JU4iKJi4zt8echThQMZZ+cO4MNOWpZW18K5G+83Gcg3iaPb4rrd6pMERBSecgAQkC9VE4kk2w6CR05zSGWauUGw1GuAAwjYoEhyKwegYAPQEuA2EDpGwAGwpdjgFUUTwQSgKSAh6UkvjgnlwmDgYAqYzg4A8fWMzAAjK0Gf5kGhMNgQkRyAByTxgMBKvFwEXwZgAJklby2n12iRMsvMCus9icrhh32VDgKGp04H64QAzAbLUadglpaY5RYuLZHC5ffalTYHCBnQZXcYaCMxhKyCik7hXngxZqiTF0xKoOUwDQKX4nLS7KM-FiGdq82j9amhunM7hdTniYmG0wiyWyyyYJWOTXDR9w74612xp6m6ixq33R369Oe8XS3By4OqyT1t6x3aJ0A) that illustrate my need

PS: using TS 4.5

**[Edit]** As suggested by @eldar, I tried using overloads:

```js
function toUpper(input:string) :string;
function toUpper(input : undefined) :undefined;
function toUpper(input :string | undefined){
     if(!input)  return undefined;

    return input.toUpperCase();

}
```

However, it does not compile

[link to updated playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAYw9gdgzgLgBAcwKYwMpgLZNTATgSwgTgF44AKQgBwFcYAuOWAogSkecOJID44BvYHGFxcKGrghwARNTpx8UGXADUCiLRgBuYAF9goSLEQp0WHCwQBZAIYBPAEZIAqhAAmSAGaEkb0hTkGJjwudmDLOAAfOBp3Lx8-XgEhETEYCSlKDToAOlgbXBgoAHV8GAALcmkbaVZWOAB+dU04RliPbwhfHX1gT1iQGHxIOBgwZyoqJFwszXpONlaFhB1+iEHhqTGJqZnA1pi4zt96+nb4rrdVgaGR7cnp2fl5kKIow46E1kEASAVPcgAQkC9VE4kkHwu3QMIjB6QhgRy912AGEbFAkORWDo9AYAPR4uA2QY0GwAGzJdlG5UU4S4SgKSDhGV8cE8uEwcDAFWmcHAHkM0HgzAAjAdlv5kGhMNhXghyAByTxgMAK7FwQXGZgAJnFcve52OiRM0vMctsjhcRwSiocBTVOnAQvCAGY9RFooaEpLTDKLFwLU5XJ9LoqbA4QA6DE7jDQHrgxWRkY9ReqCTF42KoOUwDQyX4nKM7FM-Oi6URNfA47tdUnxvHyDq04Tq9Nddnc-m4IWYMXWWWJZ7rZdKxndm66zsU3gXc2x9M3R28wWmb2S0SlIPIUbgEA)

Comment: You can use function overloading instead of generics here like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mp8Jbm)

Comment: Your code works only because you are using constants (I guess). If you apply the overload in my playground link, it won't compile. See my updated playground in the question, with your suggestion applied.

Comment: In the [doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#writing-good-overloads), we can read `Because both overloads have the same argument count and same return type, we can instead write a non-overloaded version of the function:`. Maybe what I want to achieve is simple not possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```js
type PreventLiteralString<T> = T extends string ? string : T;

function toUpper<T>(arg: T): PreventLiteralString<T> | T {
  if (typeof arg === "string") {
    return arg.toLocaleUpperCase() as PreventLiteralString<T>;
  } else {
    return arg;
  }
}

const a = toUpper("test"); \\ a: string
const b = toUpper(undefined); \\ b: undefined
```

Point of `PreventLiteralString` is that just using `T` doesn't work. It also cannot be replaced by `string`, since we get assignability error:

```js
function toUpper<T>(arg: T): T {
  if (typeof arg === "string") {
    return arg.toLocaleUpperCase() as T; // If `as string` compiler errors here.
  } else {
    return arg;
  }
}

const a = toUpper("test"); \\ a: "test" !!!
const b = toUpper(undefined);
```

Sadly use of `as` is needed, due to [compiler defering evaluation of `extends`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72620953/type-foot-is-not-assignable-to-type-t-extends-string-string-foot-fo).